# Angular caching in localStorage

Tags: javascript, angularjs, local-storage, angular-local-storage

I am trying to write a service in Angular that will cache data to localStorage, without much success! I need your help. I have several "lookup" datatypes that don't change very frequently, such as broker codes and airline codes.

I remember reading in one of my (many!) tech books that it is possible to wrap a promise around any data type, and I am taking this approach in writing my service. Essentially, I want to return the value from localStorage if it exists, then return immediately with a resolved promise. Or, in the case that it doesn't exist, I want to $http.get() it and return the promise returned from this call.

My pseudocode would look like this:

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .service("lookupDataService", function() {
        this.brokers = function() {
            var cachedBrokers = localStorage.getItem("brokers");

            if (!cachedBrokers) {
                $http.get('/api/brokers')
                    .success(function(data) {
                        localStorage.setItem("brokers", data);
                        // return promise
                    });
            } else {
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                deferred.resolve();
                // shoehorn the data from localStorage
                return deferred;
            }
        }
    })
```

Is this approach sound? How do I return a promise and the data to the calling behaviour?

**EDIT**

I realised I wasn't doing my dependency injection correctly. I have modified my pseudocode to look like this:

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .service("lookupDataService", ['$q','$http', function($q, $http) {
        this.brokers = function() {
            var cachedBrokers = localStorage.getItem("brokers");

            if (!cachedBrokers) {
                return $http.get('/api/brokers')
                    .success(function(data) {
                            localStorage.setItem("brokers", data);
                        }
                    );
            } else {
                return $q.when(cachedBrokers);
            }
        }}]
    )
```

It occurred to me that my method wasn't returning a promise until the internal promise was resolved. I think. Head-scratching moment.

M

Comment: Did you take a look at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#caching?

Comment: I did @MichaelBenford, but my $http() caching was having no effect so I decided to write my own service.

Answer (score 1):

I would look into NGStorage,http://ngmodules.org/modules/ngStorage.

```
    <script>
  angular.module('app', [
    'ngStorage'
  ]).

  controller('Ctrl', function(
    $scope,
    $localStorage
  ){
    $scope.$storage = $localStorage.$default({
      x: 42
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: That looks great, but it appears to be a different interface to localStorage, which I'm not having a problem with. My problem is with the construction of promises and returning a resolved promise along with data to the service caller in the case that the data is already present in the cache.

Comment: I'd recommend using ngStorage aswell, makes life so much easier and their is loads of documentation to help you out if needed. If you have the time it maybe worth checking the ngBook out! 


https://www.ng-book.com/
https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage

Comment: Ok will do but for the moment I'm concentrating on promises...;|

Comment: If this is for school, yes. But if this is for a work environment, use NGStorage...

Comment: @TGarrett -- I'm evaluating this ngStorage...I wouldn't use it since it hooks directly to the `$scope`, as far as I can see. It looks very tightly coupled. How can I use it in a service? What if I want to fetch a file and then set it to local storage?